# Java Graphics Error: Static / Nonstatic mishap

Tags: java, swing, graphics

So, I was working on a project of slots, because I wanted to get familiar with the java graphics library. The setup worked rather flawlessly. Then, I tried drawing a line to test the graphics, and got the error:

`engine.java:9: non-static method drawLine(int,int,int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
        java.awt.Graphics.drawLine(1, 2, 11, 12);
                         ^
1 error`

I went with the advice of my friend and created a new `engine` and named it `e`, then instead of doing `drawloop()` I did `e.drawloop`, but got the same error.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class engine{
    public void drawloop(){
        java.awt.Graphics.drawLine(1, 2, 11, 12);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                 public void run()
                 {
                    display();
                 }
                });
        engine e = new engine();
        e.drawloop();
    }
    public static void display(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Pinnacle Slots");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(768, 512));
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using swing properly. At all.

Comment: Take a look at this simple example I created for another question.

https://github.com/anubiann00b/JFrameExample

Comment: You are trying to call a non-static member of `Graphics` class. You need a object of `Graphics`. If I remember awt programming correctly your canvas/container should have a repaint() (or something like that) method that framework will call by passing object of Graphics class.

Comment: You need to create a JFrame, and add a JPanel. However you need to write your own classes extending JFrame and JPanel to intercept the repaint method. The repaint method contains a Graphics object as a parameter which you use to draw stuff.

Comment: @Puru-- that was a really useless comment; that doesn't help at all.

Comment: Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: @AnubianNoob I pressed enter early.

Comment: @Puru-- Hehe that happens to me all the time, sorry.

Comment: Looking at peeskillets link, you don't need a JFrame, just a JPanel.

Comment: Don't listen to your "friend" and certainly don't make wild guesses. Read the tutorials and follow them. See @peeskillet's link for more.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the wrong "painting" call is being used. Normally, one overrides the built in paint() or paintComponent() methods.

An example for use with your code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) { //This is where that instance of Graphics comes in
    super.paint(g); //necessary for the actual JFrame to paint itself
    g.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY); //and, very simply, draw the line
}
```

This Will be called automatically on run, but if you want to call it again manually (or to draw the line at some other location) just use

```
repaint().
```

Also, a good practice is to set a contentPane for your JFrame. You can use a custom JPanel/JComponent or simply use

```
 setContentPane(getContentPane());
```

In the display() method.

I hope this helps you and anyone else with this issue!